# Database Integrity Concerns: Missing FK Constraints and Vacuum Process Implications

Tags: database, postgresql, windows, vacuum, orphaned-objects

Version - PostgreSQL 10.21, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit

Platform - Windows

We are currently experiencing issues in the database where foreign key (FK) constraints are missing, leading to orphaned rows. Upon investigation, we suspect that we are currently running a vacuum on tables according to a schedule, and also as a standalone process when the product is not running.

Is there a possibility that during the vacuum process, FK constraints might be dropped and recreated for restructuring? If so, are there any chances that they will not be recreated?

Comment: Vacuum will not drop FK constraints. Something else is doing this. Check the Postgres log.

Comment: Why do you think that VACUUM would execute DDL statements? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-vacuum.html